# Cannot install TimeManager 0.7: no module named six

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I was able to extract and copy `dateutil` to `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\dateutil` and the error saying that `dateutil` wasn't found disappeared. But now I am getting the error `no module named six`. Tried extracting the content of the PyPi package to `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\six`, but the error remains. I suspect it's because there is no such thing such as `__init__.py` in the folder. So how do I "install" `six`, given my somehow special QGIS-Python configuration (without the usual `C:\python27\`)?

Comment: Is that the latest version because I have never needed that before?

Comment: Should be, yes. http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dateutil is needed since I added support for months in time steps. No idea what "six" refers to though. On OSgeo4W simply install matplotlib from the lib section and you will have the correct working version of dateutil.

You can find all this info on the plugin homepage https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager

> Dependencies
>
> QGIS:
>
> Requires QGIS >= 1.7 with Python 2.7
>
> other plugin dependencies: Python module dateutil (included e.g. in matplotlib available in OSGeo4W)

Comment: Installing matplotlib did the trick. I first thought I can just copy the dateutil package inside C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\dateutil but somehow that generated this error with `six`. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out, again.

Comment: One more thing.. could it be that the "forever" attribute in 0.7 is broken? `An error occured while trying to add layer gps_start_flash to TimeManager.
gps_start_flash: The attribute specified for use as end time contains invalid data` when specifying "forever" (both with and without ") as end time

Comment: Same in 0.6....

Comment: Does the data contain a field called "forever"?

Comment: stupid me - sorry for wasting your time.. ;-)